# How to use ValidationUtils in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to use ValidationUtils as follows. But I cannot instantiate errors object since Errors is an Interface. Can you tell me how I can make this working without using a validator?

```
     if(visitorDetails==null)
    {
        Errors errors;
        visitorDetails=new Visitor(); 
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "VisitorInfo", "Selected Visitor Details Not Found");
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Read this : [Validation...](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

However you must implement the Validation interface in a class, and than use it to validate your object, and to do that you autowire validator in your controller..

This is an example:

```
public class PersonValidator implements Validator {

    /**
    * This Validator validates *just* Person instances
    */
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return Person.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(e, "name", "name.empty");
        Person p = (Person) obj;
        if (p.getAge() < 0) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "negativevalue");
        } else if (p.getAge() > 110) {
            e.rejectValue("age", "too.darn.old");
        }
      }
}
```

and in your controller:

```
....

    @Autowired
    private PersonValidator personValidator;

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(final HttpServletRequest request, final ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(personValidator);
    }
...
```

Comment: Can I use this for json post ? Or this binder is only for form posts ?

Comment: Yes, using the `@RequestBody` annotation, it can be used with a JSON body post. See example https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/017-validate-spring-rest-webservice-request/

Answer (score 3):

> Assuming you are using Spring Boot.

If using application.properties (under project/src/resources) put the following in it:

```
spring.messages.basename=validation
```

Now put a validation.properties (under project/src/resources) and put the following (for example) in it:

```
NotEmpty=This field is required.
```

Your model (AppUser in this case) should have:

```
private String useremail;
getters/setters;
```

Create a component (Class) like this (example):

```
@Component
public class UserAddValidator implements Validator {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return AppUser.class.equals(aClass);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
    AppUser user = (AppUser) o;

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "useremail", "NotEmpty");

}
```

}

The following goes to your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") AppUser userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    useraddValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "userregistration";
    }

    userService.save(userForm);

    model.addAttribute("success", "User " + userForm.getUsername() + " created successfully");
    return "success";

}
```

Last but not the least, in your view put similar to this:

```
       <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-3" for="useremail">Email-ID</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <spring:bind path="useremail">
                    <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                        <form:input type="text" path="useremail" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Email-id" autofocus="true"></form:input>
                        <form:errors path="useremail">${emailerror}</form:errors>

                    </div>
                </spring:bind>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The result should look (something) like below:

[image]

You can look [HERE](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spring/boot/rocks/validator/UserAddValidator.java) for more validations.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want to get the errors object. 
In your case I would suggest below approach.

```
if(visitorDetails==null)
{
    visitorDetails=new Visitor(); 
    Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(visitorDetails, visitorDetails.getClass().getName());
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "VisitorInfo", "Selected Visitor Details Not Found");
}
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use it to make some constraint on some of your field like show error when the field is empty or emptywithspace , this class already contain some static method that can do that 
below an exemple for using ValidationUtils class 

public class UserValidator implements Validator {


    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Employee.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "email", "email");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "password", "password");

        Employee emplo = (Employee) target;

          if(emplo.getEmail() != null && emplo.getEmail()=="aa") {
              errors.rejectValue("email", "email invalide ");

    }
```